# Error 621 - Windows VPN -Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn

Error 621 - Windows VPN -Windows 7, I tried to restart the computer , restart remote access manager , copy rasphone.pbk , change rights to rasphone.pbk , refresh the ip stach with renew ip .

Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I recreated the user profile.